# Recovering the covering curve in Parshin's construction

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, algebraic-number-theory

A key step in the proof of Mordell's conjecture by Faltings' is a construction due to Parshin, which allows one to show that there is a finite-to-one map between the sets

$$\displaystyle \{K\text{-isomorphism classes of pairs }(X,P) \text{ where } X \text{ is a curve of genus } g \text{ defined over } K $$
$$\displaystyle \text{ and having good reduction outside of } S \text{ and } P \text{ is a } K\text{-point on } X\}$$

to

$$\displaystyle \{K'\text{-isomorphism classes of curves } X/K' \text{ with genus } g' \text{ and good reduction outside of } S'\}.$$

Here $K$ is a number field, $g \geq 2$, and $S$ is a finite set of places of $X$, and $K'$ is a finite extension of $K$ and $S'$ is a set of primes of $K'$ containing all primes above $S$.

Mazur gave a construction of such a cover here: https://www.ams.org/journals/bull/1986-14-02/S0273-0979-1986-15430-3/S0273-0979-1986-15430-3.pdf

The argument seems to be that one first turn $X$ into a Riemann surface $Z$, then using the structure of the Jacobian and Riemann surface theory one obtains a covering (of Riemann surfaces)

$$\displaystyle Z_P \rightarrow Z^{(2)} \rightarrow Z.$$

Then Mazur argues that "by some standard algebraic geometric arguments and elementary algebraic number theory, one shows that there is a field $K'$ which depends only on the triple $(K,S,g)$ such that $Z_P$ is the Riemann surface of an algebraic curve $X_P$ defined over $K'$". This paragraph is quite mysterious to me. Can anyone point to a reference where this is expanded upon in more detail, or explain the argument to me?

Comment: How about section 25 (page 94) of J.S. Milne's lectures on abelian varieties? https://www.jmilne.org/math/CourseNotes/AV110.pdf

Comment: @VesselinDimitrov thank you very much, I found the notes very helpful and I think they answer all the questions I had.